# How do i run the procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

```
exec home_lending_cus('9999999999', 'HOME LENDING', '11111111')
```

I am trying to run the above statement but it is throwing a error mentioned below.

```
ORA-00933: SQL Command not properly ended.
ORA-06512: at 'HOME_LENDING_CUS', line 6
ORA-06512: at line1
```

All the variables of type `varchar2`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE home_lending_cus(
    id_no    VARCHAR2,
    prod_nme VARCHAR2,
    rpt_dte  NUMBER) authid current_user
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE immediate 
  ' CREATE TABLE abc AS
  SELECT bt.id,
    ct.cus_id
  FROM bnkr_tbl bt ,
    cus_tbl ct ,
    base_tbl bt
  WHERE bt.id  =ct.id
  AND ct.id    =bt.c_id
  AND bt.pr_nme='||prod_nme|| '
  AND bt.dte   ='||rpt_dte|| '
  AND bt.id    ='||id_no|| '
  GROUP BY bt.id,
    ct.cus_id';
END home_lending_cus;
```

Comment: In which context/application do you try to execute the procedure? Might be just a missing `;` at the end of the line...

Comment: This means you have a syntax error in your PL/SQL code.  You haven't posted the source so we cannot tell you what it is.  However, the message includes the LINE NUMBER so you know exactly where to look.

Comment: Source is here
create or replace procedure home_lending_cus(id_no varchar2, prod_nme varchar2, rpt_dte number)
authid current_user as
begin
execute immediate ' create table abc as
select bt.id, ct.cus_id
from
bnkr_tbl bt
,cus_tbl ct
,base_tbl bt
where
bt.id=ct.id
and ct.id=bt.c_id
and bt.pr_nme='||prod_nme||
'and bt.dte='||rpt_dte||
'and bt.id='||id_no||
'group by bt.id, ct.cus_id';
end home_lending_cus;

Comment: @MuralidharA, edit your post to contain that code.

Comment: Please post the `create table` statement for `bnkr_tbl`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Aramillo pointed out, the quotes around the string variables are wrong, which is making the dynamic SQL not work. However, I would strongly recommend shifting to bind variables, rather than concatenation. Not only will this prevent that kind of error, it will protect you from SQL injection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE home_lending_cus(
    id_no    VARCHAR2,
    prod_nme VARCHAR2,
    rpt_dte  NUMBER) authid current_user
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE immediate 
  ' CREATE TABLE abc AS
  SELECT bt.id,
    ct.cus_id
  FROM bnkr_tbl bt ,
    cus_tbl ct ,
    base_tbl bt
  WHERE bt.id  =ct.id
  AND ct.id    =bt.c_id
  AND bt.pr_nme= :1
  AND bt.dte   = :2
  AND bt.id    = :3
  GROUP BY bt.id,
    ct.cus_id' using prod_nme, rpt_dte, id_no;
END home_lending_cus;
```

---

Or, rather, it would if you were allowed to use bind variables in DDL. Given that limitation, my inclination would be to split this into two commands.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE home_lending_cus(
    id_no    VARCHAR2,
    prod_nme VARCHAR2,
    rpt_dte  NUMBER) authid current_user
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE immediate 
  ' CREATE TABLE abc (bt_id number, cus_id number)'
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  'INSERT INTO abc (bt_id, cus_id)
  SELECT bt.id,
    ct.cus_id
  FROM bnkr_tbl bt ,
    cus_tbl ct ,
    base_tbl bt
  WHERE bt.id  =ct.id
  AND ct.id    =bt.c_id
  AND bt.pr_nme= :1
  AND bt.dte   = :2
  AND bt.id    = :3
  GROUP BY bt.id,
    ct.cus_id' using prod_nme, rpt_dte, id_no;
END home_lending_cus;
```

---

There are a couple other issues with this code that you may want to consider:

1. Your query is also invalid because you're using the alias `bt` twice in the same `FROM` clause.
2. I'd recommend using SQL-99 style joins, rather than the comma-separated list of tables.
3. Oracle code that creates a table on the fly is always a little suspect. do you really need to create a table, or can you use a global temporary table? The latter is almost always going to be the better option.

Comment: It is throwing the same error. Can u also add the exec procedure command for this.

Comment: ORA-01027 -bind variables are not allowed for data definition operations
ORA-06512 : at "home_lending_cus", line 5
ORA-06512 : at line 1
,
I tried to run -
exec home_lending_cus('99999999', 20140912)